# Future/Promises Code in Shiny Observer | Dynamic Dropdown List

Tags: r, promise, shiny, future

I am trying to integrate Future/Promise code in a dropdown for a web app. The problem is that it runs very slow processing each dropdown tab. I have been trying to see how future/promises could be helpful but having trouble getting the code to run without errors.

My issue, is where exactly in the code to place future calls, and the promise pipe operator. Again this is just to speed up the dropdown tabs.

```
# Observer that watches for Macro Dropdown change and updates dropdowns

        observeEvent({
        req(input$fMIDdropDown)
        req(input$RMDD1)
        input$RMDD1 
        input$RMDD2 
        input$RMDD3 
        input$RMDD4 
        input$RMDD5 
        input$RMDD6 
        input$RMDD7 
        input$RMDD8 }, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = T, priority = 10, {
          disable("SubmitDD")
          disable("ClearDD")
          disable("RMDD1")
          disable("RMDD2")
          disable("RMDD3")
          disable("RMDD4")
          disable("RMDD5")
          disable("RMDD6")
          disable("RMDD7")
          disable("RMDD8")
          RMDD1 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD1), input$RMDD1, "%")
          RMDD2 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD2), input$RMDD2, "%")
          RMDD3 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD3), input$RMDD3, "%")
          RMDD4 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD4), input$RMDD4, "%")
          RMDD5 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD5), input$RMDD5, "%")
          RMDD6 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD6), input$RMDD6, "%")
          RMDD7 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD7), input$RMDD7, "%")
          RMDD8 <- ifelse(!is.null(input$RMDD8), input$RMDD8, "%")    
          TemplateName <- input$TemplatedropDown

          MIDIndex <- MIDTable$macro_product_id[input$fMIDdropDown == MIDTable$product_name]

          #### Capture Selected Forecast Start Date
          StartDate <- as.Date(input$ForecastStartDD, "%Y-%m-%d")
          StartYear <- as.numeric(format(StartDate, "%Y"))
          StartMonth <- as.numeric(format(StartDate, "%m"))

          #### Get Forecast Set ID associated with MID and Start Date
          ForecastSet <- GetForecastSetByDate(MIDIndex, StartYear, StartMonth)[1,1]
          lapply(length(GetDropDownNames(MIDIndex)[[1]]):1, function(j) {

            # Progress Bar for drop down build  
            withProgress(message = 'Updating drop down selector', detail = j, value = 0, {
              for (n in 1:1) { incProgress(1) }     
            })



            ValSelect <- input[[paste0("RMDD", j)]]
            DDTitle <- GetDropDownNames(MIDIndex)[j,1]
            DDValues <- UpdateDropDowns(paste0("source_attribute_", j), 
                                        MIDIndex, 
                                        ForecastSet,
                                        TemplateName,
                                        RMDD1, 
                                        RMDD2, 
                                        RMDD3, 
                                        RMDD4, 
                                        RMDD5, 
                                        RMDD6, 
                                        RMDD7, 
                                        RMDD8)[,1]



            updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                                 inputId = paste0("RMDD", j), 
                                 DDTitle, 
                                 DDValues, 
                                 selected = ValSelect, 
                                 options = list(maxOptions = 100000)
            )
          })
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with `promises` or `async programming` but the following paragraph from the "Why use promises?" section of the documentation might be relevant:

> While promises can make a huge difference in the scalability of a
>   Shiny app, they make relatively little difference in the latency of a
>   single session. That is to say, if a Shiny application is slow when
>   only a single user is hitting it, converting it to use promises is
>   unlikely to make it perform any faster (and in fact may slightly slow
>   it down). Promises will just help prevent other sessions from being
>   slowed down by one session’s computations.

I suggest you go through the documentation and watch Joe Cheng's talk at `rstudio::conf 2018` to learn about its scope and limitations. Especially some examples from the talk would be of interest to you.

Documentation: [Promises](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/index.html)
Talk: [Scaling Shiny apps with async programming (June 2018)](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/scaling-shiny-apps-with-async-programming-june-2018/)

Comment: Thank you, I have actually seen the talk and read the documentation. This is more for Future which splits the processes across cores for parallel processing. Which is what I need for the multiple drop-downs. Currently, It processes one by one in sequence that slows everything down.